# Value of type 'FetchedResults<OtherVariables>' has no member 'theVariable'

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have read all the answers on a question with the same error but none of the answers aided me. I think my error has a different causation. The error is Value of type 'FetchedResults' has no member 'theVariable'. My code is in swiftUI and I'm using Core Data. I have all my code below and I've produced a minimum, reproducible example.

ContentView.swift ⬇️

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var otherVariables: FetchedResults<OtherVariables>

    @EnvironmentObject var variables: MyVariables

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if otherVariables.theVariable { // Error happens here
                Button(action: {
                    otherVariables.theVariable = false // and here
                }) {
                    Text("button")
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            variables.writeData(context: context)
        }
        

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

MyVariables.swift ⬇️

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class MyVariables : ObservableObject {

    func writeData(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        let otherVariable = OtherVariables(context: context)

        otherVariable.theVariable = true

        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
    
}
```

Persistence.swift ⬇️

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FetchedVariables_have_no_member")

        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.swift ⬇️

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct FetchedVariables_have_no_memberApp: App {
    
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    @StateObject private var variables = MyVariables()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

picture of [xcdatamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdKhB.png)

Comment: `otherVariables` is a container, not a single CoreData object. Iterate over it or access first or last object, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to swiftUI and using CoreData. Is there an article you could point me to or a quick answer on how to access the last object of a container?I haven't been able to find any good information on this since everyone shows how to save and fetch items in a list instead of fetching a single instance of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FetchRequest returns a `FetchedResult`. It will fetch all objects of your entity type. You can loop over all like that and access every variable for each object..

```
ForEach(otherVariables, id:\.self) { otherVariable in //<< Loop through all
    Text(String(otherVariables.theVariable)) //Access every variable
}
```

Or access only the last one with `last`, which returns an optional of otherVariable

```
Text(String(otherVariables.last?.theVariable ?? 0)) // << Access the last Item and its variable
```

Comment: Thanks! What's funny is that I eventually came up with something very similar to the first option in your answer as I was waiting for an answer on here. I cycle through otherVariables.theVariable with a ForEach and I set another variable to it's value. This is because I have other variables that are booleans and I need to use them in the conditions of an if statement. I think next time I do this I'll use the second option in your answer though. That'll cut down the work load :).